# Select by className e copying a style... where is my error?

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting crazy with this piece of code:

```js
function copia() {
  var parA = document.getElementsByClassName("A");
  var parB = document.getElementsByClassName("B");

  for (i = 0; i < parA.length; i++) {
    parB[i].style.backgroundColor = parA[i].style.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

```css
.A {
  background-color: #FFFFC2;
}

.B {
  background-color: #ccffff;
}
```

```html
<p class="B">ONE</p>
<p class="A">TWO</p>
<p class="B">THREE</p>
<p class="A">FOUR</p>
<input type="button" value="CLICCA" onclick="copia()">
```

In theory, clicking on the button should copy the background color from all elements of class A in the corresponding element of class B (assuming that both has the same number of elements). But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

`parA[i].style.backgroundColor;` will get the backgroundColor from the style attribute.  To get the actual value, you need to do:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(parA[i]),
parB[i].style.backgroundColor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

Code example

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {

    var parA = document.getElementsByClassName("A");
    var parB = document.getElementsByClassName("B");
    
    for (i = 0; i < parA.length; i++) {
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(parA[i]);
       parB[i].style.backgroundColor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
    }
    
});
```

```css
.A {
    background-color: #FFFFC2;
}

.B {
     background-color: #ccffff;
}
```

```html
<p class="B">ONE</p>
<p class="A">TWO</p>
<p class="B">THREE</p>
<p class="A">FOUR</p>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="CLICCA">
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use .onclick(), or similar attributes from a userscript! (It's also poor practice in a regular web page).

The reason is that userscripts operate in a sandbox ("isolated world"), and onclick operates in the target-page scope and cannot see any functions your script creates.

Instead, use events. HTML now has id for easier binding, but no longer has onclick()

```
<body>
<p class="B">ONE</p>
<p class="A">TWO</p>
<p class="B">THREE</p>
<p class="A">FOUR</p>
<input id="copyButton" type="button" value="CLICCA">
</body>
```

JS now binds an event to HTML element and executes a function bond to action. In this context, the function is your own and action is a click.

```
var copia = function()
{
var parA = document.getElementsByClassName("A");
var parB = document.getElementsByClassName("B");

for (i=0;i<parA.length;i++)
{
console.log("clicked");
parB[i].style.backgroundColor = parA[i].style.backgroundColor;
}

}

document.getElementById ("copyButton").addEventListener ("click", copia, false);
```

The actual problem is already explained but I feel this is important enough to improve your code in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that addEventListner is a better programming technique, but for my students is far easier to learn event handling with onclick.